Designing a table with a lot of numbers, how do I make it look clean?
I'm working for a client who is switching from an old UNIX system to a web-based application for their internal system. There are several columns of numbers in colored chips. The colors have meaning (green=free, blue=book, red=full) but it looks cluttered when they are all together.
The columns for the numbers: min=minimum participants (ignore the hashtag), kont = contingent, geb = booked, frei = free spaces, ez = single rooms, dz = double rooms.
If the number in D has a H or D it means its only half booked and there is a space open for another person.
How can the numbers be presented in a cleaner way?


Please add the image instead of the link.

A big problem with the current layout is that you're using color and only color to convey information, which isn't accessible to people with colorblindness.
I would recommend you take a step back and look at this from the user's perspective. What is the user trying to do in this moment? Do they need to see every single room with its nitty-gritty capacity details? Perhaps (as an example) you could simply show each room's max. capacity and how many spots are available, while hiding the other details in a Details view.
Gather some more information on the user's intent, and if you can, talk to users about what they need at hand vs. what can be hidden.
